# how to combine the elements of a list representing the elements of a Bash command to a new list featuring the equals symbol

Tags: python, list, command, arguments, equals

I have a list like the following:

```
commandOptionsAndArguments = ['myBigTool', '--num-callers', '30', '--leak-check', 'full', '--tool', 'memcheck', '--suppressions', 'etc/valgrind-root.supp', '--suppressions', 'Gaudi.supp/Gaudi.supp', '--suppressions', 'oracleDB.supp', '--suppressions', 'valgrindRTT.supp', '--suppressions', 'root.supp/root.supp', '--mySpecialFlag', '$(which python)', '$(which athena.py)', 'athenaConf.pkl']
```

This list consists of elements of a Bash command featuring options and, if they have them, their respective arguments. I want to convert it to the following list:

```
commandOptions = ['myBigTool', '--num-callers=30', '--leak-check=full', '--tool=memcheck', '--suppressions=etc/valgrind-root.supp', '--suppressions=Gaudi.supp/Gaudi.supp', '--suppressions=oracleDB.supp', '--suppressions=valgrindRTT.supp', '--suppressions=root.supp/root.supp', '--mySpecialFlag', '$(which python)', '$(which athena.py)', 'athenaConf.pkl']
```

This new list consists of the options and, if they have them, their respective arguments combined using the equals sign into new elements. The next step would be either to execute this command using subprocess or to convert it to a string for use with `os.system`:

```
" ".join(commandOptions)
# 'myBigTool --num-callers=30 --leak-check=full --tool=memcheck --suppressions=etc/valgrind-root.supp --suppressions=Gaudi.supp/Gaudi.supp --suppressions=oracleDB.supp --suppressions=valgrindRTT.supp --suppressions=root.supp/root.supp --mySpecialFlag $(which python) $(which athena.py) athenaConf.pkl'
```

My question is: How can I change the list `commandOptionsAndArguments` to the list `commandOptions` in a robust way, detecting both options with arguments and without arguments appropriately?

(Also, if anyone has any better names for the lists mentioned, feel free to suggest them. I'm not sure of the words I should be using to describe the way of using the equals sign to specify the arguments of command options as opposed to using whitespace.)

Comment: How would you expect to make a difference between say --suppressions and --mySpecialFlag ? Based on the format (dash-separated vs CamelCase) ?

Comment: Yup, that's a problem and I'm looking for suggestions on it. Would you suggest a reasonable approach?

Comment: I don't see anything simple and elegant and might depend on how you build that list or how much you can change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re` module here.

```
>>> commandOptionsAndArguments = ['myBigTool', '--num-callers', '30', '--leak-check', 'full', '--tool', 'memcheck', '--suppressions', 'etc/valgrind-root.supp', '--suppressions', 'Gaudi.supp/Gaudi.supp', '--suppressions', 'oracleDB.supp', '--suppressions', 'valgrindRTT.supp', '--suppressions', 'root.supp/root.supp', '--mySpecialFlag', '$(which python)', '$(which athena.py)', 'athenaConf.pkl']
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?![^()]*\))', re.sub(r'(--\S+)\s+(\w\S+)', r'\1=\2', ' '.join(commandOptionsAndArguments)))
['myBigTool', '--num-callers=30', '--leak-check=full', '--tool=memcheck', '--suppressions=etc/valgrind-root.supp', '--suppressions=Gaudi.supp/Gaudi.supp', '--suppressions=oracleDB.supp', '--suppressions=valgrindRTT.supp', '--suppressions=root.supp/root.supp', '--mySpecialFlag', '$(which python)', '$(which athena.py)', 'athenaConf.pkl']
```

**Explanation:**

- `' '.join(commandOptionsAndArguments)` join all the elements in the given list with a space as delimiter.
- And this replace the spaces which are present in=between the word which starts with `--` and the word (*which starts with a word character*) with `=` symbol. So that it won't replace the spaces present in-between `--mySpecialFlag` and `$(which python)`.

  ```
  re.sub(r'(--\S+)\s+(\w\S+)', r'\1=\2', ' '.join(commandOptionsAndArguments))
  ```
- Finally this `r'\s+(?![^()]*\))'` matches one or more spaces which are not present inside the `()` brackets. By splitting the resultant string according to the matched spaces will give you the desired output.

Comment: Wow, how did that work? How did it cope with that awkward argumentless flag option towards the end?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations of how this works, with particular attention to the regex. I've really got to get familiar with it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use slicing :

```
>>> [commandOptionsAndArguments[0]]+['='.join(commandOptionsAndArguments[1:][i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(commandOptionsAndArguments)-1,2)]
['myBigTool', '--num-callers=30', '--leak-check=full', '--tool=memcheck', '--suppressions=etc/valgrind-root.supp', '--suppressions=Gaudi.supp/Gaudi.supp', '--suppressions=oracleDB.supp', '--suppressions=valgrindRTT.supp', '--suppressions=root.supp/root.supp', '--mySpecialFlag=$(which python)', '$(which athena.py)=athenaConf.pkl']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Your approach combining slicing with list comprehension is very efficient, but it doesn't cope with options that do not have an argument. The example option without an argument that I've added is ```---mySpecialFlag```. Following it, you can see that there is the program on which the executable ```myBigTool``` (a placeholder for Valgrind) runs.

Comment: @d3pd you're welcome! unfortunately i miss your edit! but glad that you fined the solution!